# Can docker images be cross-platform like rpm noarch?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to build an image over multi-arch base images (for the runtime), but not specify the cpu architecture?  This would be equivalent of .rpm "noarch" or .dep "any" arch.

When building Java and nodejs images, there is often no arch-specific content, and it would be much simpler to provide a single, universal image.

This is different than multi-arch which is building multiple copies of the same image for different architectures with the same name.  https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-platform-docker-builds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not technically possible.  The complication is not that the program you're trying to run isn't portable, but rather that the Docker image also contains its interpreter, and *that* isn't portable.

As an absolutely minimal example, consider a Docker image that just runs a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo 'Hello, world!'
```

Its Dockerfile would *look* portable:

```sh
FROM busybox
COPY hello.sh /bin
CMD ["/bin/hello.sh"]
```

But, the `busybox` image is architecture-specific; it contains the compiled binary for the C BusyBox code.  Since the derived image is the architecture-specific `busybox` base image *plus* the portable shell script, the resulting image is architecture-specific.

Similar constraints apply around a compiled JVM or Node interpreter.  At some point in the image stack you have to get down to some native compiled code that can execute the portable content.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured.

I could probably publish the same layer into some multi-arch images using buildx, but that looks like a lot of work.  Seems such a step backwards from noarch rpm for Java and NodeJS apps.